# How to use bundle to share data from adapter to a fragment in viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bundle

I need to take the data that my adapter returns from my activity in order to send it to a fragment who works inside a viewpager.

This is my adapter, it inflates some cards with titles and descriptions for news

```
public class FeedAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

/*
Etiqueta de Depuración
 */
private static final String TAG = FeedAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * View holder para evitar multiples llamadas de findViewById()
 */
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titulo;
    TextView descripcion;

    int tituloI;
    int descripcionI;
}

public FeedAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);

}

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();

    // Almacenar referencias
    vh.titulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
    vh.descripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);

    // Setear indices
    vh.tituloI = cursor.getColumnIndex(ScriptDatabase.ColumnEntradas.TITULO);
    vh.descripcionI = cursor.getColumnIndex(ScriptDatabase.ColumnEntradas.DESCRIPCION);

    view.setTag(vh);

    return view;
}

public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    final ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    // Setear el texto al titulo
    vh.titulo.setText(cursor.getString(vh.tituloI));

    // Obtener acceso a la descripción y su longitud
    int ln = cursor.getString(vh.descripcionI).length();
    String descripcion = cursor.getString(vh.descripcionI);

    // Acortar descripción a 77 caracteres
     vh.descripcion.setText(descripcion);


}
}
```

And this is the fuction in my Activity where I want to create the viewpager at the same time I'm sending a bundle with the adapter's return

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Carga inicial de registros
            return FeedDatabase.getInstance(MainActivity.this).obtenerEntradas();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
            super.onPostExecute(cursor);

            // Crear el adaptador
            adapter = new FeedAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    cursor,
                    SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

            // Relacionar la lista con el adaptador
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(adapter);

            viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), arguments);
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

But everytime a I use "arguments.putString" it returns me an error. I'm confused because I don't know what kind of ".put" I should use with the data I receive from the adapter and how Bundle really works.

Could you help me ? 
Thanks

Comment: You cannot put an Adapter inside in a Bundle as a String. The putString method is for adding Strings into a Bundle. What exactly do you want to send, an object or a simple String?

Comment: I want to send the card view that FeedAdapter returns to the fragment. Is that return an object?

Comment: You should not pass around views. It is bad practice. You could probably pass data represented by the cursor into the ViewPager. What kind of data is represented by the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Send it to the Activity and use getIntent().getStringExtra("Name") into your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

First the adapter must implements Serializable

```
public class FeedAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Serializable{
```

The bundle that works is

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putSerializable("datos",adapter);
```

And I send it to my viewpager like this

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), arguments);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

My viewPager takes the data like this

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private Bundle data;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bundle data) {
    super(fm);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    TabFragment tab1 = new TabFragment();
    tab1.setArguments(data);

    return tab1;    // Which Fragment should be displayed by the viewpager for the given position
    // In my case we are showing up only one fragment in all the three tabs so we are
    // not worrying about the position and just returning the TabFragment
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;           // As there are only 3 Tabs
}
```

}

And finally my fragment get the arguments and implements the adapter like this

```
public class TabFragment extends ListFragment {

private Bundle bundle;
private FeedAdapter adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bundle = getArguments();
    adapter = (FeedAdapter) bundle.getSerializable("datos");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs, container, false);

    ListView LV = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.lista);
    LV.setAdapter(adapter);
    return root;
}
```

}

Thanks!